# opening imap port 143 using iptables in ubuntu server

Tags: ubuntu, email

Actually for the past 1 week I am trying to open imap port in my mail server using iptables. I tried many things but still it is not opened. I am trying to configure evolution mail client with imap port 143 but it shows error

> Error while Scanning folders in "IMAP server incomingservername"

Could not connect to incomingservername: Connection refused"

Hope someone will help me, Thanks in advance.

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 6461K packets, 869M bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination        
   40  2290 ACCEPT     all  --  any    any     localhost.localdomain  anywhere           
12999 3431K ACCEPT     tcp  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere            tcp dpt:http
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  any    any     anywhere             10.0.0.0            tcp spts:1024:65535 dpt:imap state NEW,ESTABLISHED
    0     0 ACCEPT     udp  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere            udp spt:imap dpts:1024:65535 state NEW,ESTABLISHED
    0     0 ACCEPT     udp  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere            udp spts:1024:65535 dpt:imap state NEW,ESTABLISHED
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  any    any     anywhere             10.0.0.0            tcp spt:imap dpts:1024:65535 state ESTABLISHED
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  any    any     anywhere             10.0.0.0            tcp spts:1024:65535 dpt:smtp state NEW,ESTABLISHED
  120 10016 ACCEPT     tcp  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere            tcp spt:smtp dpts:1024:65535 state ESTABLISHED

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination        

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 216K packets, 61M bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination        
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  any    any     10.0.0.0             anywhere            tcp spt:imap dpts:1024:65535 state ESTABLISHED
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  any    any     10.0.0.0             anywhere            tcp spts:1024:65535 dpt:imap state NEW,ESTABLISHED
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  any    any     10.0.0.0             anywhere            tcp spt:smtp dpts:1024:65535 state ESTABLISHED
  127 68842 ACCEPT     tcp  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere            tcp spts:1024:65535 dpt:smtp state NEW,ESTABLISHED
```

netstat -an|grep 143 this gives no result!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!1:-(

sudo ufw disable sudo: ufw: command not found

Comment: Ubuntu typically also does not let servers listen off of localhost by default. On the server, run netstat -an|grep 143 and update the question with the results. Also, what imap server are you using, and is it running?

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't look like your firewall is doing anything, the policies are all to ACCEPT and all of the rules are ACCEPT.

Try disabling your firewall and see what happens.

The error message your seeing says `Connection refused` this generally means that there isn't anything listening on the relevant port. Check your service is running and check that it's configured to listen on the correct interface and port.

Comment: Can you tell me clearly where to check whether it's configured to listen on the correct interface and port. Do you mean in my mail client configuration? Thank you!